# Viewport width slightly wider than real view window WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

I prepared my own `DataTemplate` to display my own Item class objets. To set the width I use binding to `ViewportWidth` of `ScrollViewer`. This is how:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="MyItemTemplate">
        <Grid Margin="5" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
              Width="{Binding ViewportWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ScrollViewer}}}">
            ...
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
```

How I display data:

```
<TabItem Header="Shop">
            <!--<ScrollViewer>-->
                <ListView Name="ShopListView" ItemsSource="{Binding itemList}"
                      ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MyItemTemplate}"
                      ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource alternatingListViewItemStyle}"
                      AlternationCount="2"
                      ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"
                      />
            <!--</ScrollViewer>-->
</TabItem>
```

The issue is the `grid` that makes my `DataTemplate` is sliglty broader - it overlaps the right border of the `View Window`.

**EDIT**
[image: The problem is visible on the right side]
Buttons on their right edges are cut.

```
<Style x:Key="alternatingListViewItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <!-- setting up triggers for alternate background colors -->
            <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="1">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF4C85FF"></Setter>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="2">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFFF8C7C"></Setter>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

Comment: Well, i see you have plenty [**margin**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.margin(v=vs.110).aspx) of error, i guess :P

Comment: removing `Margin="5"` hasn't solved the problem :/

Comment: Hmm, no idea. If you perhaps could add a screenshot showing how exactly the issue manifests itself. It might help getting a grasp of what is going on. The XAML snippets from your question are not telling much...

Comment: Also, show the ItemContainerStyle you are using (alternatingListViewItemStyle).

Comment: Hmm... i don't know from the back of my head, but it could be that the the ScrollViewer or the ItemsPanel use some border/padding/margin somewhere internally. But i as of now i don't really know. I would need to take a closer look at what is going on inside the ListView when i sit at my workstation tomorrow...

Comment: I would appreciate that although if you won't find time - it's okey. Thank you :)

Comment: I knew it, feels good to know that my brain does not fail me completely... yet... :-P  The ItemsContainer has some padding by default (to visually separate the rendered items from the default border of the list view, i assume) Answer below...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default style of the item container element generated by the ListView for each item incorporates some padding. That means, rendered items normally have a width which is slightly smaller than the view port width.

To not let your items cross the right border of the viewport, you could set the padding of the item container to zero. This can easily be done with a simple style for the item container. Since you already provide an item container style, you could just let it set the padding property.

However, this might not be necessary. To stretch the item content across the width of the view port, you don't need to bind the Grid.Width property in your item template to ListView.ViewPortWidth. It can be done simpler: The item container can be instructed to horizontally stretch the item content by setting its `HorizontalContentAlignment` accordingly. This of course can also be done with the item container style.

The below example style (based on the style given in your question) demonstrates both setting the `HorizontalContentAlignment` and `Padding` property. If you want to keep the default padding between the items and the border of the ListView, simply omit the Padding setter from my example:

```
<Style x:Key="alternatingListViewItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">

    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />

    <Style.Triggers>
        <!-- setting up triggers for alternate background colors -->
        <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="1">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF4C85FF"></Setter>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="2">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFFF8C7C"></Setter>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```